# How to change the decimal separator from a comma to a dot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server displays decimal separator as a comma instead of a dot, so the generated script couldn't be executed.

[image: image1]

Comment: Please do not edit your question again.

Comment: i cannot embed images

Comment: Well lucky for you, I can, and did.  In the future, it would be better for you to include text rather than a screen catpure.

Comment: Leave your database the way it is. Comma/decimal separators should be determined as a presentation (UI) thing, don't try and fudge things at the storage level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This SQL demonstrates how to use the culture parameter of the [Format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
declare @f float = 123456.789;

select
  [raw]      = str(@f,20,3)
 ,[standard] = cast(format(@f, 'N', 'en-US') as varchar(20))
 ,[European] = cast(format(@f, 'N', 'de-de') as varchar(20))
```

yields

```
raw                  standard             European
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
          123456.789 123,456.79           123.456,79
```

Comment: FORMAT() requires SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @MehmetAVŞAR: Yep. Since OP didn't specify which version he didn't care; presumably since latest version is available.